# Using a session

Tags: php

My app uses information over a server. I have one line of code that connects to my database at runtime called 'stream'. Its primary function is to retrieve user device tokens from a database table named photos.

```
$result = query("INSERT INTO login(username, pass, device_token) VALUES('%s','%s','%s')", $user, $pass, $token);
```

This is very valuable information for my app. Can someone help me store the $token value from the statement above to a session so that it can be used in this method?

```
function handleMessage()
{
    $userId = $this->getUserId();
    /*$text = $this->getString('text', self::MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, true);*/

    // First, we get the record for the sender of the message from the
    // active_users table. That gives us the nickname, device token, and
    // secret code for that user.

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM active_users WHERE user_Id = ? LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute(array($userId));
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if ($user !== false)
    {   
        // Put the sender's name and the message text into the JSON payload
        // for the push notification.
        $payload = $this->makePayload($user->nickname/*, $text*/);

        // Find the device tokens for all other users who are registered
        // for this secret code. We exclude the device token of the sender
        // of the message, so he will not get a push notification. We also
        // exclude users who have not submitted a valid device token yet.

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT device_token FROM active_users WHERE secret_code = ? AND device_token <> ? AND device_token <> '0'");
        $stmt->execute(array($user->secret_code, $user->device_token));
        $tokens = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

        // Send out a push notification to each of these devices.
        foreach ($tokens as $token)
        {
            $this->addPushNotification($token, $payload);
        }
    }
}
```

I know it sounds complicated but I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: What's wrong with `$_SESSION['token'] = $token;` ?

Comment: How would I ultimately implement that in the second method for example? Specifically, note where the existing foreach statement that specifies `$token` and `$tokens` variables.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you're trying to do. Your question mentions a table named `photos`, but there's no mention of that in any of the code you posted.

Comment: You're looping over all tokens. Which one goes into the session? All of them? You could just do `$_SESSION['tokens'] = $tokens;`.

Comment: The only "statement above" is the one that inserts into the database. Isn't that just the same one that you skip in the `SELECT` query?

Comment: The question is very unclear, but the general idea of sessions is simple: Just assign whatever you want to `$_SESSION['variablename']`, then you can use it in other pages. Just make sure all the pages start with `session_start();`.

Comment: can you give plugging that session variable into the statement above that uses a PDO syntax? It uses so many different references to device tokens.

Comment: `$stmt->execute(array($user->secret_code, $_SESSION['token']))`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you really want. Like I said, the question is unclear. Where do you want to set the session variable, how will it be used? What's wrong with getting the token from the database as you already do?